# checking if a directory exists, breaking out of loop

Tags: python, for-loop, mkdir, shutil

Trying to see if a directory exist, if it doesn't move the directory into another directory, then continue into the next iteration of the loop, this is how i am doing it, managing to get the first loop to work, creating all the files correctly just the last part when moving the directory into the other , but throws an error, the error and my part of the code:

```
 File "testdraft.py", line 305, in findReplace
    if not os.path.exists('{}/'.format.replace+str(x)):shutil.move(str(x), '{}/'.format(replace))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'

 base_direct = '{}/'.format(replace)

 for x in range(1,20):
        if not os.path.exists(str(x)+'/'):os.mkdir(str(x)+'/') #this part works
        else: continue
        shutil.copy(filename, str(x))
        shutil.copy(filename1, str(x))
        frag = open("fragments_procs.in", 'w')
        frag.write(str(x) + "\n" + str(20-x))
        shutil.copy("fragments_procs.in", str(x))
        shutil.move(str(x), '{}/'.format(replace)) #believe from here and down not working
         if not os.path.exists('{}/'.format(replace)+str(x)):shutil.move(str(x), '{}/'.format(replace))
        else: continue
```

Comment: A better model is to just try to do the file move and take action if it fails. Otherwise you're creating a race-condition.

Comment: I have a function like this "func1(replace, filename1, filename), this function is called 66 times, i am trying to only make one directory in that loop not 19, that is why I am continuing after making the first directory

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite messy and hard to understand, but anyway there is a clear syntax error in the line 305

```
if not os.path.exists('{}/'.format.replace+str(x))
```

This makes no sense at all. The str.format function does not have any property called replace (which is by the way a very bad name for a variable, since the strings have a replace method)

My guess is that you want to do something like this:

```
if not os.path.exists('{}{}/'.format(replace, x))
```

Comment: I fixed my code, was missing a parenthesis, replace is a string in my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `walk`, and concatenate the sub directories everytime.

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        print os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` is a built-in method on strings so using it as a variable name makes things confusing

`'{}/'.format(replace+str(x))`

Comment: sorry, just fixed that, replace is a string part of my constructor for the function that it is in. And yes the code is quite messy, first time I am creating 19 directories copying three files in each 19 directories and moving all 19 directories into one directory at the end which is /replace.